# How to remove close (x) button from kendo-multiselect dropdown only for first element

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

In my Angular app, I am using kendo-multiselect dropdown.
When page loads I am showing first dropdown value in the input field by default.

In order to remove the (x) next to the first dropdown I am using the below CSS:

```
#problemWith .k-icon.k-i-close {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

where problemWith is the id of the kendo-multiselect. But this removes the (x) for all dropdowns which I add after this!
I tried using :first-of-type and nth child property as well but nothing seems to work.

So is there a way I could only remove the (x) for the first kendo-mutiselect-dropdown item which loads by default and keep active for other which get added there after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for the first `li.k-button` element:

```
#problemWith .k-button:first-child .k-icon.k-i-close {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have a similar problem related to kendo-multi-select. Would be great if you could have a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57138397/in-the-kendo-multiselect-how-to-show-icon-to-add-a-field